# Kill the function in one iteration and proceed to the next iteration after X seconds in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

How to skip or kill a function in one iteration if it takes too long, and then proceed to the next iteration?

My sample code is as follows.

```
for (String word : wordSet){
 try{
     lookup(word);
     // if (lookup(word)>2 seconds){
     // throw an exception. Skip this word and check next word}         
 } 
 catch(Exception TimeoutException){
    slowWordSet.add(word);     
   // check next word
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<?> future = null;
    try {
        future = executorService.submit(() -> {
            lookup(word);
        });
        future.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(future != null){
            future.cancel(true);
        }
        slowWordSet.add(word);     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the lookup method into a callable, and send it to an executor service. Store the returned future. Then poll its status every so often. if it is done, move on to the next iteration. If it is not, and the time is less than the max allowed time, sleep for a while. If time is greater than max allowed time, cancel the task, throw an exception, and continue on with the loop.